# Existence of the empty set in ZFC, not using the axiom of specification

Tags: set-theory

Some sources include the existence of the empty set as one of ZFC's axioms. Some don't, but they include the axiom of specification and prove the existence of the empty set using this axiom and first-order logic rules.

However, in the hebrew wikipedia I found the following list of axioms in ZFC:
extentionality, union, infinity, replacement, power, regularity, chocie.

Is it possible to prove the existence of the empty (or the axiom of specification, which can be used to prove the existence of the empty set) set using only these axioms?

Comment: N.B.: This may depend on the exact formulation of these axioms.

Comment: You can prove seperation using replacement.

Comment: If you want to avoid the Empty Set axiom and use Specification to prove its existence, you have to assume that some set exists, in order to apply Spec to it...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The fact that some set exists follows from the axioms of FOL; no special axiom is required.

Comment: The existence of an empty set follows from the axiom of infinity, or at least it can be formulated as saying that $\omega$ has an ampty set as an element.

Comment: @ArvidSamuelsson It does follow from infinity, but infinity is *not* needed.

Comment: But I don't like the proof from pure logic.

Comment: @ArvidSamuelsson would you mind sending me a link to a proof not using infinity (nor seperation)?

Comment: @Ben Why are you asking me? It was Voilet Flame who brough up that proof.

Comment: My bad. @VioletFlame would you mind sending me a link to a proof not using infinity (nor seperation)?